# when did numpy stop accepting floats as index

Tags: python, numpy

When did numpy stop accepting floats as index. I get an error when using a float as an index, even when I use

```
x = np.arange(10)
i = 10 / 2
print(x[i])
```

I know this was deprecated, but cannot find back what version started to throw an error. I have many students submitting solutions to programming exercises that work for them and not for me. So their version is too old, but I want to know what version they need to upgrade to (I know the latest). When did numpy implement this change?

Comment: Possible (but annoying) solution: start making virtualenvs and installing old NumPy versions, binary-ish searching for the version that starts throwing the error.

Comment: Also, consider that it might be a Python 2/Python 3 issue. On Python 2, `10 / 2` would have produced an int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's under version 1.12.0's [release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/release.html#compatibility-notes):

> DeprecationWarning to error
>
> - Indexing with floats raises IndexError,
>   e.g., a[0, 0.0].
> - Indexing with non-integer array_like raises
>   IndexError, e.g., a['1', '2']
> - Indexing with multiple ellipsis raises
>   IndexError, e.g., a[..., ...].
> - Non-integers used as index values raise
>   TypeError, e.g., in reshape, take, and specifying reduce axis.